# Quick sort not working as intended with linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, quicksort

Preface:

I do not care about the viability of my particular quick sort algorithm. That is not what the question is about. I am curious as to why the program I have already written behaves the way it does, not about why I should use the STL or whatever. This is for learning purposes. (for instance, I'm aware picking pivot as the head is not the best case -- that's not what I'm asking though)

Question:

I have a linked list composed of `Node*`s. I've written a quick sort algorithm for it specifically. It works by taking a given linked list, and recursively splitting it into sublists based on a chosen `pivot`. The pivot is always the `head` (front) of the list, and the sublists `left` and `right` are lists that contain values less than and greater than/equal to the pivot, respectively. I've almost gotten it down, but I don't know how to properly add_link the pivots. In a previous iteration, I would just add_link the pivot to the right sublist always, but that caused an infinite loop, so I ended up skipping the pivots entirely when comparing values against it. The resulting list is sorted, but it is missing every value that was used for a pivot. How should I fix this?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct Link {
    Link(int d=int(), Link* n=nullptr) {
        data = d;
        next = n;
    }
    int         data;
    Link* next;
};

struct LinkList {
  Link* sentinel;
  size_t      size;

 LinkList(Link* h=new Link, size_t s=0) {
    size = s;
    sentinel = h;
  }

  ~LinkList() {
    Link* current = sentinel;
    while (current != 0) {
      Link* next = current->next;
      delete current;
      current = next;
    }
    sentinel = 0;
  }
};

// Prototypes

Link* sort_q(Link* sentinel);
void  divide(Link* sentinel, Link* cmp, Link*& lower, Link*& greater);
Link* concatenate(Link* lower, Link* greater);

// helpful function calls quick sort
void sort(LinkList& l) {
    l.sentinel = sort_q(l.sentinel);
}


// returns false if there sentinel = null; true if add_link was successful
bool add_link(Link* sentinel, Link* add_link, Link*& end) {
    if (sentinel == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }
    Link* curr = sentinel;
    for (; curr->next; curr = curr->next) {}
    curr->next = add_link;
    end = curr->next;
    return true;
}

Link* sort_q(Link* sentinel) {

    Link* lower = nullptr;
    Link* greater = nullptr;
    Link* cmp = sentinel;

  // base case LinkList = null or sentinel->null
    if (sentinel == nullptr || sentinel->next == nullptr) {
        return sentinel;
    }

    divide(sentinel, cmp, lower, greater);

    lower = sort_q(lower);

    greater = sort_q(greater);

    return concatenate(lower, greater);
}

void divide(Link* sentinel, Link* cmp, Link*& lower, Link*& greater) {
    lower = new Link, greater = new Link;
  // lend is pointer to end of lower subLinkList
  // rend is pointer to end of greater subLinkList
    Link* lend = nullptr, * rend = nullptr;

  // loop through LinkList until end
    while (sentinel != nullptr) {
        if (sentinel == cmp) {
            sentinel = sentinel->next; continue;
        }
        if (sentinel->data < cmp->data) {
            // break current link
            Link* tmp = sentinel;
            sentinel = sentinel->next;
            tmp->next = nullptr;
      // if subLinkList is not empty, add_link current Link to subLinkList and update end pointer
            if (add_link(lend, tmp, lend))
                continue;
        // otherwise, "add_link" current Link to empty subLinkList and update end pointer manually
            lower->next = tmp;
            lend = lower->next;
        }
        else {
            // break current link
            Link* tmp = sentinel;
            sentinel = sentinel->next;
            tmp->next = nullptr;
            // if subLinkList is not empty, add_link current Link to subLinkList and update end pointer
            if (add_link(rend, tmp, rend))
                continue;
            // otherwise, "add_link" current Link to empty subLinkList and update end pointer manually
            greater->next = tmp;
            rend = greater->next;
        }
    }
    // remove dummy Link(s)
    if (lower->next)
        lower = lower->next;
    else
        lower = cmp;
    if (greater->next)
        greater = greater->next;
    else
        greater = cmp;
    // unlink cmp
    cmp->next = nullptr;
}

// connected subLinkLists
Link* concatenate(Link* lower, Link* greater) {
    Link* sentinel;

    sentinel = lower;

    while (lower->next != nullptr) {
        lower = lower->next;
    }

    lower->next = greater;

    return sentinel;
}

void print(LinkList &l) {
  for (Link* n = l.sentinel; n != NULL; n = n->next) {
    std::cout << n->data << '\n';
  }
}

int main() {
  // set up linked LinkList 8->4->5->11->7->5->3->9->null
  Link* sentinel = new Link(8 , new Link(4, new Link(5, new Link(11, new Link(7, new Link(5, new Link(3, new Link(9))))))));
  LinkList l(sentinel,5);

  sort(l);
  print(l);

  return 0;
}
```

The output I want to have is

```
3
4 // pivot missing from output
5
5
7
8 // pivot missing from output
9
11
```

but it outputs

```
3
5
5
7
9
11
```

Edit #1:

I have tried adding the pivot between concatenations, but that does not work either. It produces different results, but not quite the same. Modifying `sort_q()` and `partition()` like so:

```
Link* qsort(Link* sentinel) {
   // ... other stuff before modification
   return concatenate(lower, cmp); // changed greater argument to pass cmp which is now cmp->next = greater once finishing partition()
}

void partition(Link* sentinel, Link*& cmp, Link*& lower, Link*& greater) {
    // .. other stuff before modifications

    // remove dummy Link
    if (lower->next)
        lower = lower->next;

    if (greater->next)
        greater = greater->next;

    cmp->next = greater; // cmp points to greater (greater) sublist
}
```

The output becomes

```
3
4
5
7
0
8
11
0
```

Comment: Can we assume you've already strolled through the code line by line with a debugger, watching what happens as it happens?

Comment: your pivot node needs to go in the middle. When you call `concatenate` you skip the pivot node

Comment: There are various ways to solve it. You could set `pivot->next` to `right` and then `concatenate(left, pivot)`, I think.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I have tried that already, that gives weird outputs.

Comment: You don't want to read this, but I'm dropping it anyway: I don't see the point of the concatenate stage. You shouldn't need it.

Comment: Well laid-out question, by the way. Everything needed to answer it is here and virtually no intervention on the part of us, other than supplying the compiler, is required to run it and watch the fun.

Comment: yes, you could change the `partition` function to include the pivot in one side or the other, instead of just skipping it

Comment: i think the problem you had with infinite loop is that `next` on the pivot doesn't get set to `null`. Setting the `next` should solve it

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I've edited the original post

Comment: @user4581301 I think I've edited the original post so that it makes a bit more sense now to have it.

Comment: well, it no longer removes the dummy nodes, so you get 0's. I'm not sure why you lost the 9 yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assumptions that you can get both a lower and a greater list, and you already make sure you have at least 2 items in the list before you call divide, so that is good.

You just need to handle all the cases at the end of divide. Make sure cmp ends up in one of the two lists. Almost like you had before, but you need to handle the case where both lower and greater lists are non-empty.

```
// remove dummy node(s)
    cmp->next = nullPtr;
    if (lower->next && greater->next) {
        // we have two lists. put cmp on greater
        lower = lower->next;
        cmp->next = greater->next;
        greater = cmp;
    }
    else if (lower->next) {
        // only a lower list, use cmp on greater
        lower = lower->next;
        greater = cmp;
    }
    else if (greater->next) {
        // only a greater list, use cmp as lower.
        greater = greater->next;
        lower = cmp;
    }
```

seeing the above, handling all 3 cases, it can be simplified to this:

```
// remove dummy node(s)
    if (lower->next) {
        // we have lower node, so put cmp on greater
        lower = lower->next;
        cmp->next = greater->next;
        greater = cmp;
    }
    else if (greater->next) {
        // only a greater list, use cmp as lower.
        greater = greater->next;
        lower = cmp;
        cmp->next = nullPtr;
    }
```

then use `concatenate(lower,greater)` afterwards. Although it could be optimized to have `divide` concatenate the lists and just return the sentinel, but that's a bit more of a rewrite.

EDIT: putting it all together to eliminate your memory leak, it should be like this (note, I have not compiled or tested)

```
void divide(Node* sentinel, Node* cmp, Node*& lower, Node*& greater) {
    lower = nullptr, greater = nullptr;
  // lend is pointer to end of lower sublist
  // rend is pointer to end of greater sublist
    Node* lend = nullptr, * rend = nullptr;

  // loop through list until end
    while (sentinel != nullptr) {
        if (sentinel == cmp) {
            sentinel = sentinel->next; continue;
        }
        if (sentinel->data < cmp->data) {
            // break current link
            Node* tmp = sentinel;
            sentinel = sentinel->next;
            tmp->next = nullptr;
      // if sublist is not empty, append current node to sublist and update end pointer
            if (append(lend, tmp, lend))
                continue;
        // otherwise, "append" current node to empty sublist and update end pointer manually
            lend = lower = tmp;
        }
        else {
            // break current link
            Node* tmp = sentinel;
            sentinel = sentinel->next;
            tmp->next = nullptr;
            // if sublist is not empty, append current node to sublist and update end pointer
            if (append(rend, tmp, rend))
                continue;
            // otherwise, "append" current node to empty sublist and update end pointer manually
            rend = greater = tmp;
        }
    }
    // insert cmp node
    if (lower) {
        // we have lower node, so put cmp on greater
        cmp->next = greater;
        greater = cmp;
    }
    else if (greater) {
        // only a greater list, use cmp as lower.
        lower = cmp;
        cmp->next = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! I really appreciate the time you took to solve it. That makes things a lot clearer.

Comment: Also one last question, would you happen to know why I'm getting a memory leak? according to valgrind it's due to allocating new `left` and `right` addresses, but I'm not sure how I can compensate for that.

Comment: for sure, yes. You should delete those at end or could probably rewrite to avoid allocating them at all

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to deallocate them with recursion involved. At what point am I able to free them?

Comment: You should try to rewrite without allocating them. Initialize them to `null` and the just set `left = tmp` instead of `left->next = tmp`, and change `if` statements appropriately

Comment: I've updated with new partition function that *should* work

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see is that you *sometimes*, but not always, add the pivot to the "left" or "right" list in `partition()`. This inconsistency likely violates the desired functionality of `partition()`. However, this functionality **is not documented**. So I'll revise my assessment to say the main problem is that you have not documented your functions. The bigger your project, the more likely you are to encounter problems because of the lack of documentation.

**Document!**

I would expect to see `partition()` documented to say that it partitions the list into three pieces: left, right, and pivot.

```cpp
/// Partitions the list starting at `head` into three pieces. Data less than
/// the given partition's data is put in the `left` list, while the remaining
/// data (except `*partition` itself) is put in the `right` list. The third
/// piece consists of `*partition`, which is assumed to be in the given list.
void partition(Node* head, Node* pivot, Node*& left, Node*& right) {
```

Another option might be to immediately put the pivot in one of these lists. However, these lists are going to be sorted immediately after the call to `partition()`, and there is no need to include `*partition` in that sort. Sort left, sort right, then concatenate left, partition, and right. In addition to being faster because there are fewer nodes to sort in the next recursive call, keeping the partition node out of your lists will *guarantee* that your lists get shorter with each recursive call.

It's your call, though, since you are the designer. The important thing is to decide what functionality you want, document it, and follow that decision.

**Enforce consistency!**

Once you have specified functionality, it is easier to verify that your code respects whatever design decisions you have made. Your `sort_q()` function fails to account for the above specification in that it does not add the partition to the list. There is probably a simpler way to do this than the below, but the below serves the purpose with little re-writing of your code. (This is the end of `sort_q()`.)

```cpp
    // ** Return left -> pivot -> right, not just left -> right **
    return concatenate(left, concatenate(pivot, right));
}
```

In addition, your `partition()` function violates this specification by (sometimes) adding the partition node to one of your lists. Stop doing that. Set your links to null instead.

```cpp
    // remove dummy node(s)
    if (left->next)
        left = left->next;
    else
        left = nullptr;   // <-- null, not pivot
    if (right->next)
        right = right->next;
    else
        right = nullptr;   // <-- null, not pivot
```

Hmm... I had avoided re-writing your code earlier, but this particular structure strikes me as needlessly complicated. If a certain pointer is not null, assign it to something. Otherwise (when that pointer is null), assign null instead of the pointer (which is null, so same thing). That is rather wordy. Just assign the pointer.

```cpp
    // remove dummy node(s)
    left = left->next;
    right = right->next;
    // *** Memory leak, as we removed the nodes without deleting them ***
```

Oh that memory leak is a pain. Especially since you don't really need the dummy nodes. But that digresses into a separate question, so for now I'll just note that your code is very close to working if you had initialized `left` and `right` to `nullptr`. *(Your hint is that if `left` is initialized to `nullptr` then, at the moment `append()` is called, `lend` is null if and only if `left` is null.)*

One final piece: if you've followed all this so far, you probably ran into a segmentation fault at some point. You are missing a check in `concatenate()` (maybe the reason you started using dummy nodes?)

```cpp
// connected sublists
Node* concatenate(Node* left, Node* right) {
    if ( left == nullptr )   // <-- Add this check
        return right;        // <-- It is very easy to concatenate to nothing.
    Node* head = left;
```

That should address the immediate question. There are other places to improve, though, so keep working at it. (There are other parts of your code that I would call "needlessly complicated", albeit less severely – and less obviously – than what that `if` statement became.)